# Checkbox and button interaction in JSF

Tags: jsf, button, checkbox, valuechangelistener, woodstock

I have a checkbox:

```
<webuijsf:checkbox immediate="true" valueChangeListenerExpression="#{user$recentreports.selectSingleCBEvent}" id="selectCB" binding="#{user$recentreports.selectCB}" toolTip="#{msg.report_select}"/>
```

whose valueChangeListenerExpression method is:

```
List<RowKey> rowsToBeRemoved=new ArrayList();
public void selectSingleCBEvent(ValueChangeEvent event) throws Exception {    
     RowKey rowKey = tableRowGroup.getRowKey();
     System.out.println("rowKey" + rowKey);
     System.out.println("tableRowGroup.getRowKey().toString()" + tableRowGroup.getRowKey().toString());
     rowsToBeRemoved.add(rowKey);
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance( ).renderResponse( );

}
```

I have a button that must be used for deleting rows that checkbox component is selected:

```
<webuijsf:button actionExpression="#{user$recentreports.deleteButton_action}" id="deleteButton" text="#{msg.report_delete_selected}"/>
```

whose backing bean is:

```
public String deleteButton_action() {

        for(RowKey rowToBeRemoved:rowsToBeRemoved){
            try {
                System.out.println("rowToBeRemoved" + rowToBeRemoved);
                GeneratedReport generatedReport = (GeneratedReport) reportList.getObject(rowToBeRemoved);
                Query resultQuery = queryGeneration(generatedReport.getId());
                List<String> dropTableQueries = resultQuery.getResultList(); // generated the queries to drop r tables
                for(int i=0; i<dropTableQueries.size(); i++){
                   String aDropTableQuery;
                   aDropTableQuery = dropTableQueries.get(i);   // get single drop table query
                   entityManager.createNativeQuery(aDropTableQuery);
                   reportList.removeRow(rowToBeRemoved);
                   reportList.commitChanges();
               }
                generatedReportJpaController.delete(generatedReport);
                reportList.commitChanges();
                analyzerResultService.drop(generatedReport.getId().longValue());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error("Cannot delete report with row key " + rowToBeRemoved + e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

output of this form is:

```
[#|2011-10-17T11:47:14.304+0300|INFO|glassfishv3.0|null|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|rowKeyRowKey[0]|#]

[#|2011-10-17T11:47:14.304+0300|INFO|glassfishv3.0|null|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|tableRowGroup.getRowKey().toString()RowKey[0]|#]

[#|2011-10-17T11:47:14.304+0300|INFO|glassfishv3.0|null|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|rowKeyRowKey[1]|#]

[#|2011-10-17T11:47:14.304+0300|INFO|glassfishv3.0|null|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|tableRowGroup.getRowKey().toString()RowKey[1]|#]
```

which means my deleteButtonAction is reached but is not performing the actions that I write (getting rowKey from rowsToBeRemoved and deleting them), I don't understand why. Back bean is request scoped does it have any relevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is you short-circuit JSF lifecycle by calling FacesContext.getCurrentInstance( ).renderResponse( ) in selectSingleCBEvent and your actionListener is never reached.

ValueChangeListeners for immediate inputs are called in ApplyRequestValues phase. ActionListeners are called later in InvokeApplication phase. By calling [renderResponse](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29)() you skip the rest of the cycle and proceed directly to RenderResponse phase.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I think I need to spend more time on JSF lifecycle :)